# trouble filtering jsonb data in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to learn how to filter jsonb data. When I run:

```
SELECT DISTINCT jsonb_array_elements(data) 
FROM reports 
WHERE data @> '[{"status": "Active"}]'
```

Instead of only returning rows where `status: Active` it seems to ignore the `WHERE` clause and I also return rows that contain `status: Inactive`

Looking for some help understanding what is going on here.

The data looks like

```
[{"report": "Report1", "status": "Active"},
 {"report": "Report2", "status": "Inactive"},
 {"report": "Report3", "status": "Inactive"},
 {"report": "Report4", "status": "Active"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from reports
join lateral jsonb_array_elements(data) j(v)
on true
where
v->>'status' = 'Active'
```

here `v` is elements from jsonb array, e.g. `{"report": "Report1", "status": "Active"}`

Then filter 'status' keys, where value is 'Active', using `->>` operator